# function call from other contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I'm trying to invoke a function by interacting 2 contracts. I defined 2 contracts `ArrayTes` and  `CallFunction` within same file. `CallFunction` is calling a function `secfun` from contract `ArrayTes`

**Intercontract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


contract ArrayTes {

    uint256 public l;

    function secfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256) {

        l = l+a;
        return l;
    }
}


contract CallFunction {

    ArrayTes at;

    function CallFunction(address _t) {
        at = ArrayTes(_t);
    }

    function thirdfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256 c) {

        c = at.secfun(a);
        return c;
    }

}
```

But c is always returned as zero. I tried defining contracts on seperate file and importing it.

**ArrayTes.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ArrayTes {

    uint256 public l;

    function secfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256) {

        l = l + a;
        return l;
    }
}
```

**CallFunction.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./ArrayTes.sol";

contract CallFunction {

    address useraddress;
    constructor(address _t) public {

        useraddress = _t;
    }


    function thirdfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256 c) {

        ArrayTes instanceuser = ArrayTes(useraddress);
        c = instanceuser.secfun(a);
        return c;
    }

}
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var ArrayTes = artifacts.require("./ArrayTes.sol");
var CallFunction = artifacts.require("./CallFunction.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {

    deployer.deploy(ArrayTes).then(function() {

        return deployer.deploy(CallFunction, ArrayTes.address);
    });
};
```

Still `c` value is returned zero. `useraddress` from CallFunction is returned as '0x'. When I commented code lines `c = instanceuser.secfun(a);`from CallFunction correct contract address ie; **useraddress** was returned.  This code worked for me around 6 months back. Now its not working. I can't figure out the issue.Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
function secfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256)
```

is declared as view, but tries modifying `l`

2. `address useraddress;`

is not declared public, so of course it cannot be returned.

Here is my working solution, I think you can make it from here on:

**CallFunction.sol**

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./ArrayTes.sol";

contract CallFunction {

    address public useraddress;
    constructor(address _t) public {

        useraddress = _t;
    }

    function thirdfun(uint256 a) public view returns(uint256 c) {

        ArrayTes instanceuser = ArrayTes(useraddress);
        c = instanceuser.secfun(a);
        return c;
    }

}
```

**ArrayTes.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ArrayTes {

    function secfun(uint256 a) public pure returns(uint256) {
        uint l;
        l = l + a;
        return l;
    }
}
```

**2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var ArrayTes = artifacts.require("./ArrayTes.sol");
var CallFunction = artifacts.require("./CallFunction.sol");
var cf;
module.exports = function(deployer) {

    deployer.deploy(ArrayTes).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(CallFunction, ArrayTes.address);
    }).then(function(instance){
      cf = instance;
      return cf.thirdfun.call(3).then(function(result){
        console.log("The number is: " + result.toNumber());
      });
    }).then(function(){
      return cf.useraddress.call().then(function(theAddress){
        console.log("The address is: " + theAddress);
      });
    })
};
```

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks Nikita...I tried this code in remix...Address is returned correctly but `c` value returns zero...Here is the image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R58Kgz_Fbz8-hO4wBQiZljS9IPOvyZco/view

Comment: the image doesn't show how test.sol looks like - can you export to gist, please? Also, please try copy-pasting my solution to a truffle project and check the console output from `truffle migrate --reset`, it should definitely work.

Comment: I tried `truffle migrate --reset` still `c` value is zero. Here is the link : https://gist.github.com/angelmariadas/28498ca80994824efd7e479efb32a2ed

Comment: Did you copy it correctly into your project ? My above solution returns the desired value. That is tested even during deployment, your console will read: "The Number is: 3" and will do so with any other number entered in `return cf.thirdfun.call(3).then...`

Comment: I copied and  tried again with exact code...still same result... `solc --version` gives `Version: 0.4.25-develop.2018.6.6+commit.59b35fa5.Linux.g++` and  `truffle --version` gives `Truffle v4.1.11` . But anyway it should work in Remix right? I am not able to figure it out :(

Comment: I changed the solidity version to  `pragma solidity ^0.4.20;` in Remix  and it Worked!!!!!!!!!! :)  Same issue here : https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3969... Updated version doesn't support this code??

Comment: So in truffle it worked with 0.4.23, but in solidity it didn't and you had to go down to 0.4.20 ?

Comment: I downgraded truffle version to v4.1.5 hence `truffle version` gives  `Truffle v4.1.5 (core: 4.1.5)  Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)`. Then it worked in truffle for me with `pragma solidity ^0.4.20;`

Answer (score 0):

You will find a solution in these links:

- https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/8503
- https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16931
- https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/397

If using parity POA network, add the following lines to the "params" section in `chain.json` (the chain spec file):

```
"eip140Transition": 0,
"eip211Transition": 0,
"eip214Transition": 0,
"eip658Transition": 0
```